# Service not Stop In Android Oreo

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo

I have implemented Service in Application but need to stop service after killing App. But I got an issue in Android O. There is one Method onTaskRemoved which in not call in Orio. I am also trying to JobScheduler But getting the same issue. ANy suggestion or solution will be appreciated. :)

**Start Service:**

```
 ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                           IBinder service) {
                // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get  LocalService instance

            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            }
        };

Intent intentService = new Intent(this, ServiceClass.class);
            bindService(intentService, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

**Service Class:**

```
public class ServiceClass extends Service {
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        stopSelf();
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ServiceClass getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return ServiceClass.this;
        }
    }

}
```

**AndroidManfiest.xml**

```
<service android:name="Service"
    android:stopWithTask="false"/>
```

Comment: May I know how you stop your service ?

Comment: Yes, I am using  stopSelf() function for stop service.

Comment: 1. How you start your service?
2. Are you using bind Service?

Please add some extra code in your question that will help us to answer

Comment: @VishalChhodwani Thanks for tip. Question is updated.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#stopService(android.content.Intent)

Comment: used android:stopWithTask="true" it will stop service after closing app from recent task

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this will work for you

```
 android:stopWithTask="false"
```

Add this attribute in your service tag in manifest file.